# android open activity in popup with close image in top corner...?

Tags: android, dialog, cancel-button

May be possible that this question is already asked and answered.
But my situation is something different

I know how to open an activity like dialog(in menifest set Theme:dialog in android:theme)
Now I want a image on my dialog activity top right corner like in most html popup nowaday.
and when user click on it, it close that activity.

I just want design idea how to design that activty.
here corner cancel will be image and not shape from drawable.

[image]

Comment: You can create a background image with a close image on top right corner and set it as background

Comment: I tried with that idea, but I got nothing proper, so I'm here. Can you provide kinda xml with same.